# sum field value after using if and count in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I Get All Count Value By Following Query
But Now I Need Sum Of all This count value that i get.
How can i do thAT ?

```
SELECT pkg_name, IF(COUNT(*)<=2, COUNT(*), 2) AS total from packages GROUP by pkg_name
```

Comment: Kindly, if you want to ask `query` related question, don't assign `php` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use extra select for get data from drive table so you can sum all value from drive table

```
SELECT sum(total) as total_value
FROM (SELECT pkg_name, IF(COUNT(*)<=2, COUNT(*), 2) AS total 
      FROM packages 
      GROUP by pkg_name) final_table
```

Comment: how Can I Get Value According to date field ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this query into another `SELECT`, e.g:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS `sum`
FROM (SELECT pkg_name, IF(COUNT(*)<=2, COUNT(*), 2) AS total 
      FROM packages 
      GROUP by pkg_name) a
```